# How to write an aspect or annotation for a method that cannot update any instance variables?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

How to write an aspect or annotation for a method that cannot update any instance variables?

Say for example I have the following java class

```
public class Foo {

    String name;
    int id;

    public getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Now say I want to write an aspect or in general, some annotation call it say `@readOnly` which can enforce `getName()` method to not modify either `name` or `id` so if do

```
public class Foo {

    String name;
    int id;

    @readOnly
    public getName() {
       name = "hello world";
       id = 7564;
       return name;
    }
}
```

Any invocation of `getName()` like above should result in an error since it modifies both `name` and `id`

The class like below should be just fine since it just doing read of instance variables.

```
public class Foo {

    String name;
    int id;

    @readOnly
    public getName() {
       return name + "," + id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to inspect the bytecode (and the bytecode of everything the method might call, recursively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about directly throwing a compile error when there is any member write access in any `get*()` method?

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, FIELD, METHOD })
public @interface ReadOnly {}
```

**Sample class / driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  private int id = 1;
  private String name = "default";

  @ReadOnly
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @ReadOnly
  public String getName() {
    name = "hello world";
    id = 7564;
    return name;
  }

  public String getNameWithoutReadOnly() {
    name = "hello world";
    id = 7564;
    return name;
  }

  @ReadOnly
  public String getNameIndirectly() {
    modifyMembers();
    return name;
  }

  private void modifyMembers() {
    name = "hello world";
    id = 7564;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.getId();
    try { application.getName(); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(System.out); }
    application.getNameWithoutReadOnly();
    try { application.getNameIndirectly(); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(System.out); }
  }
}
```

**Aspect declaring compile error:**

The following aspect only detects `@ReadOnly` annotations on methods, not on classes or members. You can extend it if you also need that.

The `declare error` statement directly throws compile errors when compiling your application with the AspectJ compiler. In Eclipse you would see something like this:

[image: AspectJ declared compile errors]

If you also want to detect indirect write access from helper methods called by a getter, you also need the dynamic pointcut with `cflow()`, but that one only works at runtime, not at compile time, because it inspects the callstack. If you do not need it, just remove it.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.ReadOnly;

public aspect ReadOnlyGetterAspect {
  declare error :
    set(* *) && withincode(public * get*()) && @withincode(ReadOnly) :
      "Setting members from within a getter is forbidden";

  before() : set(* *) && cflow(execution(@ReadOnly public * get*())) {
    throw new IllegalAccessError("Setting members from within a getter is forbidden");
  }
}
```

BTW, if you want to see the runtime pointcut/advice in action, you need to make the code compile first. So you either need to weaken `declare error` into `declare warning` or comment out the two statements causing the compile errors in `getName()`.

If you do the former, your log output will be:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Setting members from within a getter is forbidden
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.ReadOnlyGetterAspect.ajc$before$de_scrum_master_aspect_ReadOnlyGetterAspect$1$3e55e852(ReadOnlyGetterAspect.aj:11)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.getName(Application.java:14)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:39)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Setting members from within a getter is forbidden
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.ReadOnlyGetterAspect.ajc$before$de_scrum_master_aspect_ReadOnlyGetterAspect$1$3e55e852(ReadOnlyGetterAspect.aj:11)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.modifyMembers(Application.java:32)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.getNameIndirectly(Application.java:27)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:42)
```

If you do the latter (fix the code), of course you will only see the second exception.

Comment: I wish I could give you +100 for this. Thanks a ton!!! Yes compile time errors are even better!

Comment: Also Do you mind uploading this code somewhere? so I can see what it takes to set it up using gradle? Again I am new to this framework.

Comment: If you feel the urge to reward me, feel free to put a bounty on the question. ;-) As for uploading the code, it is complete already, it even includes package names. The only thing missing would be a Gradle file. I am a Maven user, though. This sample project was set up as a pure Eclipse project, but I could show you how to use Maven to build it. With Gradle you would have to ask someone else, though, I am sorry. BTW, does that mean you were asking an AspectJ question without ever having built any AspectJ project by yourself? Maybe you can just google it.